# How to add a User as a Member from another IDP?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We have ADB2C tenant with a Identity Provider setup to an Okta setup in another Organization via Open ID Connect.

We have a Admin UI to add users. I see that GraphAPI has a createUser which takes a json with Password and changePwdOnFirstUse setting. This is fine to add a direct member to ADB2C.

The problem I have is that, how can I add the User from the other Okta 
 Organization so that when this user logs in to my App (and is authenticated by Okta), can login to my App.

At present, after authentication from Okta, we see User not found Error.

I suppose, I cannot add this user via Graph API using same createUser method as this user password is not something we are supposed to manage.

How do I add this other Organization user to ADB2C, so that I do not see this "User not found" issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure AD Graph API, you can [create an external account user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser), with the **userIdentities** property of the **user** object being set to the **sub** (subject) claim of Okta's ID token:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": false,
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "mailNickname": "john.smith",
  "otherMails": [
    "john.smith@company.com"
  ],
  "userIdentities": [
    {
      "issuer": "{okta-id-token-iss-claim-value}",
      "issuerUserId": "{okta-id-token-sub-claim-value}"
    }
  ],
  "userPrincipalName": "{guid}@{your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

where **issuerUserId** must be set to the base64 encoding for the **sub** claim of Okta's ID token.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Our ADB2C will be using several connections, e.g. Okta with one organization, PingIdentity with another, Auth0 for some other organization. So, in our Admin screen to add users, to our ADB2C, how can we get issuerUserId from these different SSO solution. Will we need to call some Okta Url, PingIdentify Url etc to get IssuerUserId or as ADB2C will have a OPENID connection to these, is there a generic way to get the IssuerUserId by emailaddress?